# I am unable to use the extended screen on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: nvidia-geforce

When I had just downloaded Ubuntu 23.04, The screen extension worked well and I could use 2 screens with no issues at all. Currently, I am unable to use the second screen. When i connect the HDMI cable, there is nothing that shows on the second screen.
Help me solve this.

Comment: I assume you're asking about Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 (*you don't specify which 23.04 system*), but have you changed kernel modules (drivers) on your system?  as I'd expect the changes you now have (*it no longer works, but did in the past as I understand your question*) are the result of changes you've made, but gave no details. Did you change any configs? change drivers? etc. You mention a '*screen extension*', what extension are you asking about? Did you add it? if so how? from where?